# Pseudoinverse of $I-MM^+$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, pseudoinverse

Are there any identities for the Moore-Penrose pseudoinverse that would let me simplify and analize the expression $(I-MM^+)^+$ where $I$ is the identity matrix and $M$ is a rectangular matrix of rank $r$? ($M^+$ denotes the Moore-Penrose pseudoinverse of $M$)

Ultimately I want to simplify a more complex expression, that is

$$I-(I-MM^+)^+(I-MM^+)$$

EDIT: If it is of any use, we can additionally assume that $M$ is $m\times n$ with $m\leq n$ and that its rank is either $m$ or $m-1$ (those two cases may be treated separately)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$I-MM^+$ is an orthogonal projection, so its Moore-Penrose pseudoinverse is equal to itself and
$$
I-(I-MM^+)^+(I-MM^+)=I-(I-MM^+)^2=I-(I-MM^+)=MM^+.
$$

Answer (score 0):

It´s the same matrix
consider de USV factorization of M
I-MM+=I-(U*S*VH)(V*S^-1*UH)
where UH is the transpose conjugate of U and VH is similar for V

Then I-MM+=I-U*UH
Now consider W orthonormal basis of U
thus [U W] has as inverse [UH;WH] denoted ; as column vector similar to matlab

Then I=[U W]*[UH;WH] = U*UH+W*WH

Thus I-M*M+=W*WH where WH*W=I

I-M*M+=W*WH=W*I*WH=W*I^-1*WH=(W*WH)+ = (I-M*M+)+

Comment: Welcome to math.se! Please checkout the following page for formatting: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference.